# Stream Analytics job has validation errors: Querying EventHub returned an error: ProtocolName

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

We've been having a few issues with Azure IotHub. I have a stream analytics job listening to an IotHub. My stream analytics job which was working perfectly fine just started showing no input and output. On restart it came up with the following error "Stream Analytics job has validation errors: Querying EventHub returned an error: ProtocolName." Which sort of indicates to me that it can't listen to IotHub anymore. Has anyone else had similar issues?. Help on troubleshooting this would be great.

[stream analytics job error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsN7u.png)

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with EventHub that has since been addressed which should fix this. If this problem persists, please contact support.